# ./setup.sh Permission denied

Tags: permissions

What is the problem in that?
I work in xubuntu x86_x64
I get the following error while trying to execute install_bin :

```
mohamed@mohamed:~/Desktop/installer_v3.0$ ls 
batch_installer  install_bin  installer  install.now  setup.sh 
mohamed@mohamed:~/Desktop/installer_v3.0$ ls -l
total 44
-rw-rw-rw-  1 mohamed mohamed 8533 Jan 24  2013 batch_installer 
drwxrwxrwx 13 mohamed mohamed 4096 Feb  9 19:29 install_bin
-rw-rw-rw-  1 mohamed mohamed 9179 Jan 24  2013 installer
-rwxrwxrwx  1 mohamed mohamed 9179 Jan 24  2013 install.now
-rwxrwxrwx  1 mohamed mohamed  497 Jan 24  2013 setup.sh     
mohamed@mohamed:~/Desktop/installer_v3.0$ ./setup.sh  
/home/mohamed/Desktop/installer_v3.0/installer: Permission denied. 
mohamed@mohamed:~/Desktop/installer_v3.0$
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that you're new to askubuntu. so I will start by jumping to sudo command.

try

```
sudo sh setup.sh
```

It should work because your script **setup.sh** is using **installer** also

**sudo** should work but you can do it the other way (correct way - as the other answer by @geirha):

```
sudo chmod +x installer
```

and then run your **setup.sh** as you were trying

```
./setup.sh
```

Comment: I tried this but see

Comment: not work it still say Permission denied.

Comment: after I use sudo -i it say WARNING: The Installer must not be run from a root user account.
         Instead, Installer must be run from a regular user account.
         Installing tools from a root account is not supported; in
         certain cases this may cause a tool to fail to run properly
         for some or all users

  To run installer as root (not recommended), please re-invoke
  installer with the -install_as_root switch.

Comment: @user246638 try sudo sh setup.sh -install_as_root   Or try the second solution which is safer

Comment: @user246638 have you tried the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear at what the error is:

```
/home/mohamed/Desktop/installer_v3.0/installer: Permission denied.
```

It's trying to execute the file named `installer`, but `installer` doesn't have the execute bit set, as can be seen in the `ls -l` output.

```
-rw-rw-rw-  1 mohamed mohamed 9179 Jan 24  2013 installer
```

so

```
chmod 755 installer
```

and try again.

Comment: Wrong filename. He's trying to execute `setup.sh` not `installer`

Comment: This is actually the right answer. The different filename was *intentional* as it's the `installer` file with permission issues, not the `setup` file. ( @hmayag )

Comment: @kamil: Out of fairness, this answer was here first and also explains why you need to chmod the 'installer' file.

Comment: @minerz029 but my first answer did the work and solves the problem: sudo sh setup.sh

Comment: @minerz029 And what bothers me is the way my answer was downvoted immediately before geirha put his answer although my answer was right enough to solve the problem

Comment: @kamil, downvote was from me, for jumping straight to sudo. sudo isn't the answer to everything.

Comment: @geirha Ok I got the point. +1 for comment and answer. I respect your patience. please edit your answer so I can remove the downvote

Comment: I found that the question is by a newbie. so I suggest easing the answer by 1 command so he will not be bothered from 2 commands. that's why I suggested sudo

Comment: @geirha actually I prefer to use `sudo` than `chmod` because changing the permissions of files might cause problems, besides when you install any software, say firefox, you do `sudo apt-get install firefox`, so there's nothing wrong, using sudo is normal thing when you're installing software

Comment: @Fischer, Well, even with sudo, you won't be able to execute a file if it doesn't have the execute bit... so you won't get around a chmod. And there's nothing in the question suggesting user246638 wants to install something globally.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
sudo bash
sudo su
sudo sh /.setup.sh
~/desktop/installer3.0$ ls
```

and then it might work fine this way.